# How do I specify a custom directory layout for an sbt project?

Tags: build, sbt

How do I specify a custom directory layout for an `sbt`-based project?  I've been looking at the online `sbt` material, but I'm struggling to find this information...

What I did find in the documentation were the default locations:

- Sources in the base directory
- Sources in `src/main/scala` and `src/main/java`
- Tests in `src/test/scala` and `src/test/java`
- Data files in `src/main/resources` and `src/test/resources`
- Unmanaged jar-files in `lib/`

How do I override these in the `build.sbt` file?

My project structure is currently as follows:

- Source in: `[workspace]/sandbox-scala/src/sbt/myFirst/`
- Libraries in: `[workspace]/java-lib/common/lib/`

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can override a number of sbt's default directory locations. Here's an example that overrides the directory where sbt expects to find "unmanaged" dependencies/jar files:

```
unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / "custom-jars-directory"
```

(More examples related to depndencies in [the sbt documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Detailed-Topics/Library-Management.html).)

You can also configure the directories as specific to a particular "task"... E.g., to set the directory where test-case source code is, try:

```
scalaSource in Test := { (baseDirectory in Test)(_ / "test") }.value
```

And then your core application source code could be somewhere else, say under `src/`:

```
scalaSource in Compile := { (baseDirectory in Compile)(_ / "src") }.value
```

**NOTE**: For older versions of `sbt` you may need the following (now-deprecated) syntax:

```
unmanagedBase <<= baseDirectory { base => base / "custom-jars-directory" }
scalaSource in Compile <<= (baseDirectory in Compile)(_ / "src")
```

This syntax will not work in newer versions of `sbt` (since 0.13.13, I believe).

Comment: SBT's documentation has improved, but it still needs much more work.

I have code (being ported from a non-JVM language) with a layout where tests are intermixed (but consistently using specific "Test.extension" suffixes) with non-test source code, and where to align with the existing build procedure, no build artifact should be placed within the source code area.  It is completely non-obvious to even begin to guess how one would go about setting up SBT to do this, though presumably SBT is sufficiently powerful that it should actually be fairly trivial to do.

Comment: Currently syntax for customizing test directory is: `scalaSource in Test := baseDirectory.value / "test"` (the same syntax is for production source code).

Comment: @MirMasej, I've updated the answer to reflect the newer syntax.